# Rfc2898DeriveBytes to crypto.pbkdf2

Tags: node.js, encryption

I am not getting the same results when switching from C# to JS:

Converting from this:

```
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
passPhrase,
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltValue)
);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Aes aes = new AesManaged();
aes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
aes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
cs.Close();
ms.Close();
aes.Clear();
return ms.ToArray();
```

To this:

```
crypto.pbkdf2(Buffer.from(pass), Buffer.from(salt, 'hex'), 1000, 256 / 8, null, function (err, key) {
   console.log("Key:" + key);
   crypto.pbkdf2(Buffer.from(pass), Buffer.from(salt, 'hex'), 1000, 128 / 8, null, function (err, key) {
        console.log("VID:" + key);
   }
}
```

But it's not working for some reason

I tried Buffer.from(pass, 'utf8') and so one but I am never getting the same result.

I know I have something wrong but I have no idea how pbkdf2 works

Comment: [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53119338/getting-following-error-for-aes-encrypiton-system-security-cryptography-cryptogr) problem?

Comment: I've read this question and even went through many. I am not able to reproduce the pbkdf2 key. In C# you create a Rfc2898DeriveBytes class with your params, and call GetBytes, the method generates a password which varies every time you call it (which I'm guessing is the iteration thing), however on nodejs it always returns the same value.
I tried to match the params but never reached a similarity

Comment: Turns out I was comparing C# bytes to nodejs hex, I was getting good results except for the second call for VID, so now I just have to figure out what to change, padding maybe or something

Comment: Solved it, for anyone interested, in the Rfc2898DeriveBytes documentation it is mentionned that calling GetBytes twice is the same as calling it once but with the cb (length) value being the sum of the two, so all I had to do was to sum up the length and then split the array in two parts one for the key and one for the vid

Comment: Note that it is not a good practice to derive the IV from the key. If you use your password more than once, the IV would be the same. Each message should have a unique IV - just create 16 random bytes and store them next to the ciphertext.

Comment: @t.m.adam Thanks for the input. For my specific use case I want a constant salt. So anyone can take this code and build upon it.

Comment: @FadyFadlallah Of course, but note that you can easily improve the security of your code with a random IV. The IV doesn't have to be secret, you can strore it or transmit it with the ciphertext. For example, you can create a random IV with [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) and store it in a byte array, before or after the ciphertext. The salt should also be random bytes, you can create and store it using the same method as with the IV.

Comment: @t.m.adam I will look into that thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone in the same problem as I am this is the equivalent code

```
var pass = 'password';
var salt = 'salt';
var keyLen = keylen; // aes.KeySize / 8 where KeySize is 256
var IVLen = ivlen; // aes.BlockSize / 8 where BlockSize is 128

var nodeCrypto = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(pass, salt, 1000, keyLen + IVLen, 'sha1');

// Output same values as C# Bytes
var aesKey = [], aesIV = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodeCrypto.length; i++) {
    if (i < keyLen)
        aesKey[i] = nodeCrypto[i];
    else
        aesIV[i - keyLen] = nodeCrypto[i];
}

console.log(aesKey);
console.log(aesIV);

// How to use it to decrypt
var r = fs.createReadStream(path);
var decrypt = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', nodeCrypto.slice(0, keyLen), nodeCrypto.slice(keyLen, keyLen + IVLen));
var w = fs.createWriteStream(output);
r.pipe(decrypt).pipe(w);
```

Comment: So, what are the values of `keylen` and `ivlen`?

Comment: super working solution :) nice code, used 32 for keylen and 16 for ivlen